# Re install Node js has broken npm : Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I reinstalling node js on my windows and run npm update -g.
Now everytime I run npm, I got :

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
```

Any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a path and/or npm configuration issue.  Node/NPM thinks that it should find the global module directory in the `Users\AppData` tree...and it's not there.

First, verify where you installed node.  Record that directory.

Second, verify that location is in your PATH.  You can do this by using `set` at a command prompt or other route you prefer.

Third, you can use the `npm set prefix c:\path\to\the\real\node_modules\` command to tell NPM where to find your modules.  Just use the directory you noted in the first step in place of the fake path I listed here.

Comment: thanks, it seems that I have 2 paths that pointed to 2 different folder of npm.thx for you answer